# Resident Memory (RSS) and Peak RSS

Tags: linux, memory-management, operating-system

I have a code that uses resident memory (RSS) 500MB and Peak Resident memory (RSS) 1GB. 
Should not the resident memory value and Peak resident memory value be same ?
What is the difference between them ? Over a period of time the memory may increase or decrease. So, is this a average ?